# project's Interpreter version is 3.5 still get the SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character Error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

*When I execute the migrations:*

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

**I get the bellow error:**

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe4' in file /Users/abx/Desktop/website/website/settings.py on line 40, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

But my Django project's Interpreter version is `3.5.2` in my PyCharm.

---

The bellow is part of settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',  # 会使用music的apps的config配置
]
```

The comment line is the line 40.

If I am under 2.7 I know I should add :

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

But I am under python 3.5

Comment: add your migration files which causing error.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the encoding on the first line of your file.like this for example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I know this, if I am under python 2.7, I just mean, I am under python 3.5 now, why still has this error?

Comment: This happens because the first line encoding description is part of a PEP convention as described in the error pycharm throws you. you can disable this kind of validation in the settings if you want to